# .load nao funciona se elemento já estiver carregado

Tags: jquery

Estou com o seguinte problema. 
estou usando .load para executar uma ação apos o carregamento de um iframe

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('iframe').on('load',function()
   { 
       $('#diviframe').fadeTo(200,1);
   });
});
```

Tudo funciona muito bem, exceto se o iframe carregar antes do codigo.
cheguei a essa conclusão por que testei com iframe com apenas com uma palavra (para carregar mais rapido) e com varios textos (para demorar um pouco mais para carregar).
alguem tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o código jQuery está a ser executado antes da iframe completar o carregamento.

Para garantir que esse código jQuery é executado após a iframe estar carregada, é necessário usar o $(document).ready. Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').on('load',function() { 
        $('#diviframe').fadeTo(200,1);
    });
});
```

Fica a nota que, se está a usar jQuery e não houver uma razão para a existência da iframe, talvez o melhor seja carregar o conteúdo por ajax. Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').load('http://yoursite.tld/pagina', function() { 
        $('#diviframe').fadeTo(200,1);
    });
});
```

Além disto, importa referir que

```
$('iframe').load(...)
```

e

```
$('iframe').on('load', ...);
```

funcionam da mesma forma. Aliás, o .on() é recomendado e existe a partir da versão 1.7 do jQuery (ver http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas apesar de eu não ter especificado, o codigo ja se encontra dentro de ready. É necessario o iframe pois o objetivo é upload sem refresh. Pelos testes que fiz, acredito que é o iframe que esta sendo carregado antes do codigo, pois só nao funciona quando o iframe carrega muito rapido.

Comment: Ok. Então talvez seja melhor fazer o seguinte: Retirar o código da página que inclui a iframe e colocar o $('#diviframe').fadeTo(200,1); dentro de um $(document).ready na própria vista (página) da iframe. 
Assim, o seu código só depende da iframe.